# Expression Validator gives "Unable to get a property on a non-object"

Tags: symfony

can anybody figure out why this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('networkLoIp', IntegerType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new A\NotBlank(),
                new A\Expression(array(
                    'expression' => 'value <= this.getNetworkHiIp()'
                ))
            )
        ))
        ->add('networkHiIp', IntegerType::class, array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new A\NotBlank()
            )
        ))
        ->setMethod('post')
        ;
```

gives an error like this: **"Unable to get a property on a non-object"** ?

When I dump data after submit I can see values I've put inside the form.

**EDIT**

A very similar error I get after moving expression to options, i.e.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $optionsResolver)
{
    $optionsResolver->setDefaults(array(
        'constraints' => array(
         new A\Expression(array(
            'expression' => "value['networkLoIp'] <= value['networkHiIp']"
        ))
        )
    ));
}
```

**"Unable to get an item on a non-array."**

Comment: Don't you forget a `,` here: `new A\NotBlank(),` ? (in the 1st add)

Comment: yes, however problem still exists.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem comes from this part of code ?

Comment: yes, while changing this.getNetworkHiIp() to anything (for ex. an integer) it works. It looks like "this" isn't the instance of the Entity, but no idea why.

Comment: why this sentence hsave this syntax? `value['networkLoIp'] <= value['networkHiIp']`

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case you can use this:

```
$builder
    ->add('networkLoIp', IntegerType::class, array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new A\NotBlank(),
            new A\LessThanOrEqual($this->getNetworkHiIp())
            // or if the method is static and defined somewhere else
            // new A\LessThanOrEqual(ThatObject::getNetworkHiIp())
        )
    ))
```

Reference for [`LessThanOrEqual`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/LessThanOrEqual.html).

If the field stores an IP address I would use [`Ip`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Ip.html) validator as well.

Comment: I can't. It's Form Class and getter is inside the Entity class. Executing your code gives me Attempted to call an undefined method named "getNetworkHiIp" of class "AppBundle\Form\CreateLicenceType".

Comment: I see, what if you make that method static and call it like `ObjectWithMethod::getNetworkHiIp()` or you could move that method into the form class?

Comment: Maybe that would work, but that's not my goal. In this particular case I'd rather keep all the validators in the Form class. If no solution cames up I will do the Expression Validator in annotations inside entity, cuz it works there.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use AppBundle\Form\CreateLicence

class crateLicenciaonType extends AnstractType{

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $entity= new CreateLicence();

    $builder
        ->add('networkLoIp', IntegerType::class, array(
    'constraints' => array(
        new A\NotBlank(),
        new A\LessThanOrEqual($entity->getNetworkHiIp())
        // or if the method is static and defined somewhere else
        // new A\LessThanOrEqual(ThatObject::getNetworkHiIp())
    )
))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply expression contrainst on a non object but you can use [an other one for the same purpose](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) or create an object (DTO) link to your form.