# Use Expression constrainst on non object

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form like it:

```
class FeatureDynamicSequenceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('upstream', IntegerType::class, [
                'data' => 0,
                'constraints' => [
                    new LessThan([
                        'value' => 1000,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('downstream', IntegerType::class, [
                'data' => 0,
                'constraints' => [
                    new LessThan([
                        'value' => 1000,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('showUtr', CheckboxType::class,[
                'data' => true,
                'label' => 'Show UTR',
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('showIntron', CheckboxType::class,[
                'data' => true,
                'required' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

In this form, I would like add a Constrainst that check:
If showUtr or ShowIntron are not checked, then upstream and downstreal can't be > to 0.

Then I want something like it:

```
->add('upstream', IntegerType::class, [
    'data' => 0,
    'constraints' => [
        new LessThan([
            'value' => 1000,
        ]),
        new Expression([
            'expression' => 'value > 0 && (this.showUtr || this.showIntron)',
            'message' => 'You cannot set upstream if you do not display UTRs and introns.',
        ]),
    ],
])
```

But I can't use it, because it's not an object, value give me the value of the upstream field (it's ok), but I can't access to the showUtr or showIntron value...

EDIT: try with Callback closure

```
->add('upstream', IntegerType::class, [
    'data' => 0,
    'constraints' => [
        new LessThan([
            'value' => 1000,
        ]),
        new Callback([
            'callback' => function($data, ExecutionContextInterface $executionContectInterface) {
                dump($data);
                $executionContectInterface->addViolation('You cannot set upstream if you do not display UTRs and introns.');
            },

        ])
    ],
])
```

I have the same problem, $data just contain the field value.

I don't really want to create an Entity, because I don't persist it... And I can't believe there is not a solution to check it whithout creating an Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601877/2134945)

Comment: I've tried with Callback to, but the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: You have to use the Callback constraint in `$resolver->setDefaults(['constraints' =>...])` in the `configureOptions` method

Comment: Yes if I place the test in the configureOptions, I can access to the whole data, then in this place I've tried Expression and Callback work both. The difference is, in the Callback, I can define on wich field display the error. In Expression, I have a general form error.

Comment: I thought I could set the error on the desired field with atPath, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes you could. Normally this should works : `$context->buildViolation('YourError')->atPath('yourField')->addViolation();`

Comment: I'ts ok with: `->atPath('[upstream]')` in place of `->atPath('upstream')`. I don't know why use bracket, but it's needed.

Comment: I looked from my side and personally, I don't need brackets even if my FormType is not link to an object

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => [
            new Callback([
                'callback' => function($data, ExecutionContextInterface $executionContectInterface) {
                    if ($data['upstream'] > 0 && (!$data['showUtr'] || !$data['showIntron'])) {
                        $executionContectInterface->buildViolation('You cannot set upstream if you do not display UTRs and introns.')
                            ->atPath('[upstream]')
                            ->addViolation()
                        ;
                    }
                },
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

The full code is:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('upstream', IntegerType::class, [
            'data' => 0,
            'constraints' => [
                new LessThan([
                    'value' => 1000,
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('downstream', IntegerType::class, [
            'data' => 0,
            'constraints' => [
                new LessThan([
                    'value' => 1000,
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('showUtr', CheckboxType::class, [
            'data' => true,
            'label' => 'Show UTR',
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('showIntron', CheckboxType::class, [
            'data' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => [
            new Callback([
                'callback' => function($data, ExecutionContextInterface $executionContectInterface) {
                    if ($data['upstream'] > 0 && (!$data['showUtr'] || !$data['showIntron'])) {
                        $executionContectInterface->buildViolation('You cannot set upstream if you do not display UTRs and introns.')
                            ->atPath('[upstream]')
                            ->addViolation()
                        ;
                    }
                },
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
}
```